# could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: macos, xampp

I am using xampp on mac os but I open a web laravel project and I got an error how to fix it. thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Af6Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

This web project on windows I can still use without error